# custom AngularJS filter ignores my parameter and receive some other scope.data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, module, angularjs-scope

I have a very strange problem. Made a custom AngularJS filter:

Here is a part of it:

```
angular.module('filterModule', []).
    filter('nscode', function () {

        return function (input) {

            console.log('input:');
            console.log(input);

           (...)
```

Then I call this filter here:

```
<ol ui-tree-nodes="" data-nodrop-enabled="false" ng-model="node.i" collapsed="true" data-nodrag ng-class="{hidden: collapsed}">
    <li ng-repeat="node in node.i | nscode:{data: scope.data, code: nscodeinput}" ui-tree-node data-nodrag 
        collapsed="true"
        ng-show="visible(node)"
        ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'">
    </li>
</ol>
```

You would think that my nscode filter would receive **{data: scope.data, code: nscodeinput}**, but instead I get:

```
input:
filterModule.js:8 [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

This is the content of node, from ng-model. I really don't understand why this happens?

I just what to pass an object to my filter, but it keep getting the node element instead, no matter what parameters I set.

Comment: could you provide an example of the actual object you want to pass as assume you don't want to pass {} but rather a variable

Comment: Sure @Visualife, changed the html to show the object I want to pass.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it:

```
    return function (array, input) {
```

For some reason it sends the array of the ng-model even if I don't ask for it. So my filter needs to take two parameters. the second one receives the arguments I send to my filter.